# SPARQL CONSTRUCT subClassOf

Tags: sparql, rdf, linked-data

i want to create a construct query with triples of subjects, that has a certain subclass.
That works fine:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX AS: <http://www.w3.org/ns/activitystreams#>
CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o}
WHERE {
    ?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* AS:Create ;
    ?p ?o .
}
```

But now i want to ask for more than one type!
Something like

```
WHERE {
    ?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* AS:Create|AS:Announce ;
    ?p ?o .
}
```

any idea ?

Comment: `VALUES ?cls {AS:Create AS:Announce} ?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* ?cls ;`

Comment: reference as usual in the W3C specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `VALUES` clause for this:

```
VALUES ?cls {AS:Create AS:Announce} ?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* ?cls ;
```